# IntelliJ Idea output console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path

[Hi, I'm new to IJ Idea and I've noticed every time that I run a program, I see four different paths printed out in the console along with my desired output. It also takes a few seconds to print any program that I'm trying to print compared to PyCharm, which prints out in a flash. Is there something that I can do to minimize this path to get a faster printout?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TkBX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think there is.

```
Process finished with exit code
```

Will always be there, but that does not slow down your program. Neither does the path with information about the file and the IJ edition. Printing something simple should take under 100 ms; something complicated still only should take 2-3 seconds. I will keep researching to see what can be done to make it building faster.

Comment: Not really an answer. I would have commented if I could...but not enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The "paths" are just parameters that Intellij is passing to the JVM; given that you haven't manually added any extra parameters, it's likely you can't remove them. The slowness is also unlikely to be related to these parameters, it's just the time required for IntelliJ to launch the compilation process and run the program.

There are alternative VMs/projects that are meant to have a faster start time (GraalVM, Quarkus??) - you could try something like that if you're feeling adventurous.

You could try to avoid having to frequently rerun your code, for example by having unit tests to test it, or don't quit after the code is done - depends on the use case.